# NSString Encoding problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, core-foundation

My code

```
char* tmp = "abc \x80 dfg";
NSString* name = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:tmp];
```

It returns `name` as `nil`. I understand `-initWithUTF8String:` method doesn't like my  extended-ascii \x80 (euro sign). I tried to play with `-initWithCString:` with all encoding possible. Nothing works.

Interestingly Apple sample code below works properly

```
 [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"Long \xe2\x80\x94   dash"];
```

I can't figure out how to use their approach. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

U+0080 is an invalid Unicode codepoint (the Euro sign is U+20AC). It's valid (and the Euro sign) in Windows CP-1252, however:

```
NSString* name = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:tmp encoding:NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding];
```

(The reason Apple's code works is because of the way UTF-8 characters are represented in bytes.)

Answer (score 1):

The UTF-8 code for € is three bytes long, and it goes: \xe2\x82\xac.

For translating between Unicode code points and UTF-8, you can use the following site: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl . I took the code point for the Euro sign from Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

The C99 \u character escape for € is **\u20ac**

So, €1.99 will be:

```
NSString *euroString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"\u20ac1.99"];
```

Also check this out for more info: [using UTF-32 in NSString](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2010/Jun/msg01174.html)